# DocumentAttachmentMap Query for Attached File

Tags: email-template, contentdocument, emailfileattachment

I can attach a file to a Lightning [emailTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailtemplate.htm) using one of the emailTemplate editors in Salesforce but I have not been able to find the attachment record that makes this relationship possible.

If, for example, I have an emailTemplate with id '00X0t000000MJ24EAG' and I attach a file to it, I can verify that the file is related to the emailTemplate by opening the emailtemplate in the emailtemplate editor associated with the email component on a lead record page. The file will be shown attached to the emailTemplate below the email HTML body rich text editor (image attached). However, when I query the [DocumentAttachmentMap](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_documentattachmentmap.htm#sforce_api_objects_documentattachmentmap) object with either of the following two queries, no results are returned (I also queried ContentDocumentLink):

```
select id from DocumentAttachmentMap where parentID = '00X0t000000MJ24EAG'
```

or

```
select id from DocumentAttachmentMap
```

How do I find the record which associates the file I attached with the Lightning emailTemplate?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved this. The documentAttachmentMap is kind of a red herring. Although the API reference states that it "maps the relationship between an EmailTemplate and its attachment, which is stored as a Document," I couldn't see how it was actually used in this example. The relationship between a Lightning EmailTemplate and attachments is determined by a ContentDocumentLink. I've appended the Apex code I used to attach a file to an emailTemplate, which is the same as the code used to attach a file to any other record.

```
ContentDocumentLink contentlink=new ContentDocumentLink();
contentlink.ShareType= 'V';
contentlink.ContentDocumentId = '0690t000000cmOgAAI';
contentlink.LinkedEntityId = '00X0t000000MJ24EAG';
insert contentlink;
```

My question related to a project where I created a replacement for the Lightning emailTemplate system. Understanding the relationship between emailTemplates and files was necessary so that I could query for any emailTemplate attachments before sending a template-based email.